# New Google Play Services Admob permissions error

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

I am testing out the new google Admob implemented through Google Play Services.

This is all being done through code and no xml at all, except for the android manifest

```
private Activity   m_activity;
private AdView     m_adview;
private AdRequest  m_adrequest;

public void init_admob() {
    Log.d("--test--admob--", "Admob Init started");

    m_adview = new AdView(m_activity);
    m_adview.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-9986005637768452/7524337670");
    m_adview.setAdSize(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);

    Log.d("--test--admob--", "Admob Init finished");

}

public void show_banner() {

    Log.d("--test--admob--", "Admob building add request started");
    m_adrequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
    .addTestDevice("TEST DEVICE ID")
    .build();
    Log.d("--test--admob--", "Admob building add request finished ");


    Log.d("--test--admob--", "Admob attempting to show ads");
    m_adview.loadAd(m_adrequest);
    Log.d("--test--admob--", "Admob finished building ads");

}
```

After I call show_banner, I get the log messages up until

```
Log.d("--test--admob--", "Admob attempting to show ads");
```

and then the app just hangs with the error code below.

```
Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.ew.c
W/ActivityManager( 2282): Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.gsf.gservices.GservicesProvider from ProcessRecord{42624eb8 1701:com.test.admob/u0a398} (pid=1701, uid=10398) requires com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES or com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.WRITE_GSERVICES
W/ActivityManager( 2282): Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.gsf.gservices.GservicesProvider from ProcessRecord{42624eb8 1701:com.test.admob/u0a398} (pid=1701, uid=10398) requires com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES or com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.WRITE_GSERVICES
W/ActivityManager( 2282): Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.gsf.gservices.GservicesProvider from ProcessRecord{42624eb8 1701:com.test.admob/u0a398} (pid=1701, uid=10398) requires com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES or com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.WRITE_GSERVICES
W/ActivityManager( 2282): Permission Denial: opening provider com.google.android.gsf.gservices.GservicesProvider from ProcessRecord{42624eb8 1701:com.test.admob/u0a398} (pid=1701, uid=10398) requires com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES or com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.WRITE_GSERVICES
V/WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider( 1701): Binding Chromium to main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {422237d8}
```

android manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" 
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />

<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

[EDIT]
I forgot to mention that I've also tried adding but that didn't work either.

Comment: What version of GPS? What version of Android have you deployed on? What is minSDK and targetSDK in your Android Manifest?

Comment: min sdk 10 test device galaxy note 4 44 latest update.

Comment: Appears to be a bug in the 7.0 client SDK when the service apk on the device is outdate or isn't there at all (e.g. Kindle). An internal bug has been filed for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in version 4.3 of Google Play Services.
See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-admob-ads-sdk/sePctoDJbRg%5B1-25%5D

Answer (score 0):

Add the following permission to your menifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

Comment: I tried this before READ and WRITE_GSERVICES but that doesn't work the app still hangs.